# Login System Using Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: security, google-app-engine, web, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I use oauth to make a login System using google cloud Endpoints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but this is a basic workflow.

Usually the login system is different from the users profile. Authenticate the user using Oauth natively on the client - the authentication will return a profile id. Use that profile id to create a profile for the user on your system.