# Can you set up a simple log on system with google endpoints

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have a demo to create which needs to have 3 different log on types. I am not very familiar with PHP and have been using the google app engine with endpoints quite recently.

I am looking to have a simple log on system with a user name and password and i have set up 3 different entity types (admin, merchant and store manager).

The only problem is that all the objectify queries that are created need to be pre defined and cannot search for a user with a username and password matching the correct one specified on the index page which means i can't retrieve the data from the datastore using the API's unless i filter it before had which won't work for a log on system.

Comment: Are you talking Java or PHP?

Comment: apologies, i added a java tag but forgot to mention it in the description. I am using java in Eclipse EE

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165549/login-system-using-google-cloud-endpoints

Comment: I'm trying not to use the oauth system as it requires a google account and i will only have the one available as it is a demo. I have found out though that you are able to specify a dynamic filter for the query using a query form and i will post the links and solutions if i find that it works as intended. thank you for the help though @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 2):

> The only problem is that all the objectify queries that are created
>   need to be pre defined and cannot search for a user with a username
>   and password matching the correct one specified on the index page
>   which means i can't retrieve the data from the datastore using the
>   API's unless i filter it before had which won't work for a log on
>   system.

not really sure what you mean by this, nor where you got this info. But implementing a login simple is pretty straightforward using endpoints + objectify. Just query for a user, if the user is not null check for the password and act accordingly.

```
   @ApiMethod(name = "loginUser", path="login")
    public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest req, HttpServletRequest context) {
        //TODO user search para buscar los usuarios?
        UserAccount user = ofy().load().type(UserAccount.class).filter("username", req.getUsername()).first()
                .now();
        if(user == null){
            // return error
        }
        if(user.getPassword().equals(EncryptionUtils.encrypt(req.getPassword()))){
        //do whatever session handling you like
    }
}
```

Comment: I aggree with this solution. If you absolutely must filter for user and password at once you'd need a composite index. But there really is no need to create expensive indexes for this kind of usage.